# man has missing parts

Tags: command-line

Since about a week ago, the man pages on my Debian box have bits missing. e.g. The command line options are missing. Here is an example of `ls`:

```
LS(1)                                              User Commands                                              LS(1)

NAME
       ls - list directory contents

SYNOPSIS
       [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  Sort entries alphabetically if none of
          nor     is specified.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       ,
              do not ignore entries starting with .

       , 
              do not list implied . and ..

              with , print the author of each file

       , 
              print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters

                 =SIZE
              with , scale sizes by SIZE when printing them; e.g., '--block-size=M'; see SIZE format below
```

Comment: That title made me go "ouch!"  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When pasting the text from `man` to the question, I discovered that the problem is not with man. (I manualy edited question to look correct)

The problem is that the terminal colours are configured badly (one of the foreground colours was configured that same as the background colour).

To test this, select all the text. The selection, temporarily, changes the text colour. This may reveal the problem.

Comment: Alternative workaround available for some terminals - give it a `TERM` that's compatible but without colour, e.g. `TERM=vt100 man ls` in XTerm.